.net ef migration error "no schema has been selected to create in"
I can't figure out where i made a mistake.
I have 2 schemas in my db (Postgre): BooksStore and PollHub.
My project should use BooksStore. I use ef code-first method to create tables in schema.
So I google for two days and trying every possible solutions but nothing really work.
Here some fragments from my code:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.HasDefaultSchema("booksstore");
    builder.Entity<BookEntity>().ToTable("Books", schema: "BooksStore");

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}

My connection string: "Host=;Port=5432;Database=postgres;SearchPath=BooksStore;Username=postgres;Password=;"
I tried without searchpath - all the same.
I can provide more code fragments or something else if it necessary.
I granted usage and create for my schema to public and postgres role (but I guess it has usage and create by default as owner).
Does someone know what sould I try next. Is there a problem with my db configuration?

Be careful with case, booksstore <> BooksStore, better remove schema from ToTable.

If Schema already exists you can write below and table will create
make sure schema name should exact same as you created and also check case
public BooksContext(DbContextOptions<BooksContext> options) : base(options) { }

public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.HasDefaultSchema("BooksStore");
}



Is code-first correct? "I have 2 schemas in my db (Postgre): BooksStore and PollHub. My project should use BooksStore. I use ef code-first method to create tables in schema." If you have something in the database, is code-first the correct choice?

Your context should look like in the answer by @Harshini if code-first is correct choice.


public BooksContext(DbContextOptions<BooksContext> options) : base(options) { }

public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.HasDefaultSchema("BooksStore");
}


Make sure that you have created the migration. Without migrations, no changes to database will be done About EF Core Migrations. Also, it seems like you may have more than one DbContext, in this case you will need to provide, which context to run Migrations with multiple DbContext

You need to apply pending migrations either using terminal or in code. My preferred method is to run them on app startup. Something like this assuming it's a web app:


using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<BooksContext>();
    context.Database.migrate();
}

Hope this helps :)
